# Can't extract src attribute from "img" from Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to extract the pictures' URL from a website.
I try multiple solution on this below code but no solution help me out.
In this I want separated products images.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedrive/chromedriver.exe')

wshoes = []
url= "https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-lifestyle-shoes-13jrmz5e1x6zy7ok"
driver.get(url)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
time.sleep(4)
time.sleep(7)
# Get scroll height
"""last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

this doesn't work due to floating web elements on youtube
"""

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
conte = None

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    
    if new_height == last_height and conte:
       print("break")
       break
       
    last_height = new_height
    time.sleep(5)
    pageSource = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
    conte = soup.find_all('div',class_='product-card__body') 

    images = conte.find('img', {'class':'product-card__hero-image css-1fxh5tw'},src=True)
    print(images)
```

Comment: You imported `pandas, Numpy` & Haven't used them in code & Question Tags, what to do with `pandas`? Why you tagged `Pandas`?

Comment: oh Sorry I forgot thanks

Comment: Show us what this code does, and explain what you wanted instead.

Comment: Basically I want products Images links only

Answer (score -1):

You can try using selenium:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for image in images:
    imageClass = image.get_attribute('class')
    if imageClass == 'product-card__hero-image css-1fxh5tw':
        print(image)
```